# Nested function as attribute in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7

Not sure if this is a dupe or not. Here it goes.

I need to write some Python code that looks like:

```
class TestClass:
    def test_case(self):
     def get_categories(self):
      return [“abc”,”bcd”]
     # do the test here
```

and then have a test engine class that scans all these test classes, loads all the test_case functions and for each invokes get_categories to find out if the test belongs t the group of interest for the specific run.

The problem is that get_categories is not seen as an attribute of test_case, and even if I manually assign it

```
class TestClass:
    def test_case(self):
     def get_categories(self):
      return [“abc”,”bcd”]
     # do the test here
     test_case.get_categories = get_categories
```

this is only going to happen when test_case first runs, too late for me.

The reason why this function can’t go on the class (or at least why I want it to be also available at the per-function level) is that a TestClass can have multiple test cases.
Since this is an already existing testing infrastructure, and the categories mechanism works (other than the categories-on-function scenario, which is of lesser importance), a rewrite is not in the plans.

Language tricks dearly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested functions don't become attributes any more than any other assignment.

I suspect your test infrastructure is doing some severely weird things if this isn't supported (and uses old-style classes!), but you could just do this:

```
class TestClass:
    def test_case(self):
        # ...

    def _get_categories(self):
        return [...]
    test_case.get_categories = _get_categories
    del _get_categories
```

Class bodies are executable code like any other block.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is nested classes. Functions aren't made to do what you are trying to do, so you have to move up a notch. Function attributes are mainly used as markup, whereas classes can have anything you want.

```
class TestClass(object):
    class TestCase(object):
         @classmethod
         def get_categories(cls):
             return ['abc', 'efg']
```

Note that I used `@classmethod` so that you could use it without instantiating `TestCase()`; modify if you want to do `test_case = TestCase()`.

Comment: Elegant and clean, but I am not going to do that kind of heavy change to an already existing infrastructure with ~700 tests in it for the sake of a minor feature :)